# ERROR when using find_all_by Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, findall

I am having trouble with my table in ruby. I am allowing a user to search for a class by a prefix or a title, so that sends them to a found_by_prefix or found_by_title page and I need to use the `find_all_by_prefix(params[:prefix])`. So when I did that I was getting an error so I researched it and found that using `<%=@course.map(&:prefix).join(', ')%>` would put all the courses found in my table but it only puts all the results in one row. I just want to know how to make 4 rows for the 4 results!

Controller:

```
def found_by_prefix
      @course = Course.find_all_by_prefix(params[:prefix])
 end
```

View:

```
    <table border=1>
<tr><th>id</th><th>prefix</th><th>number</th><th>title</th><th>section</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><%=@course.map(&:id)%></td>
<td><%=@course.map(&:prefix).join(', ')%></td>
<td><%=@course.map(&:number).join(', ')%></td>
<td><%=@course.map(&:title).join(', ')%></td>
<td><%=@course.map(&:section).join(', ')%></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the results, creating a row for each one:

```
<% @course.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= course.id %></td>
        <td><%= course.prefix %></td>
        <td><%= course.number %></td>
        <td><%= course.title %></td>
        <td><%= course.section %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Also, you should probably name your instance variable `@courses` instead of `@course` because it represents a collection, not a single model object.